# sort array and get first key in jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays, sorting

I'd like to sort the array by its value and get the key of the first value afterwards.

```
var obj = { name1:2, name2:3, name3:1 };


var temp = [ ];
$.each(obj, function(key, value) {
temp.push({k: key , v:value});
});
temp.sort(function(a,b){
if(a.v > b.v){ return 1}
if(a.v < b.v){ return -1}
  return 0;
});

console.log(temp[1]);
```

temp[1] gives me the first object, but how do i get the key of the first object?

Comment: have you tried: `temp[1].k` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might find this sorting array a little more versatile; you can retrieve the key by name when calling the function, then you could store it in a different array and call the first value.

```
function sortByKey(array, key) {
    return array.sort(function(a, b) {
        var x = a[key]; var y = b[key];
        return ((x < y) ? -1 : ((x > y) ? 1 : 0));
    });
}

var people = [
    {name: 'bob'},
    {name: 'joe'},
    {name: 'amy'}
];

people = sortByKey(names, 'name');
alert(people[0].name);
```

Comment: this is great; I just added a second value, to make it work. var people = [
    {name: 'bob', myitem: 1 },
    {name: 'joe', myitem: 3 },
    {name: 'amy', myitem: 2 }
];

Comment: Ah, yep -- I've had that function saved for years, it's come in REALLY handy ;)

Answer (score 2):

`temp[0].k` will hold the `k` key you created

Answer (score 2):

To get the keys from the object you can use [`keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys). For example:

```
var obj = { name1:2, name2:3, name3:1 }; 
var obj_keys = obj.keys();
```

This will return `["name1", "name2", "name3"]`.

Since you're storing the key in `k`, it may be as trivial as:

```
temp[0].k // First item is index 0.
```

Comment: Do note that this is for browsers that support ``obj.keys`` (ie9+)

Comment: @NickTomlin Ah yes, that is an important caveat.

Answer (score 1):

`how do i get the key of the first object?`

You have an array `temp` and you are *pushing* objects onto that array with two properties, `k` and `v`. To access those properties, you can use dot notation like so:

```
var k = temp[index].k;
var v = temp[index].v;
```